# How to recognize iPhone contact change programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to know about any change in iPhone contacts like number change, picture change, etc.

I have already fetched iPhone contacts, now if any new number is added to contacts, then I need to recognize about this in my app.

Comment: Please elaborate .....

Comment: Refer to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/BasicObjects.html Address Book section

Comment: can we use ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback to detect iPhone contacts change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out the `ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback` function. It's sort of a weird API  but this will allow you to receive a callback when the address book changes in a different app or thread. Your local cached address book should not be affected by these changes. I don't think there are any convenience functions for telling what changes were made but you may be able to manually find some changes by comparing your cached version to a new `ABAddressBook` instance